# jsfiddle does not work well with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this simple snippet that works on my localhost but it doesn't on jsfiddle ?
https://jsfiddle.net/vfbvsn7g/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
<body> 
<script> 
var myNames = [ 
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'}, 
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'}, 
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]; 

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); 

app.controller('myController',function($scope){ 

$scope.names=window.myNames; 

}); 
</script> 
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> 
<p>Looping with objects:</p> 
<ul> 
<li ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}</li> 
</ul> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: from settings dropdown in javascript frame select Load type as Wrap in Head. it will work

Comment: Another person runs into jsFiddle's idiotic^H^H^H^H^H^H *surprising* default of wrapping everything in an `onload`: https://jsfiddle.net/vfbvsn7g/10/ The converse of [*code fails to work outside a jsFiddle*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272728/code-fails-to-work-outside-a-jsfiddle)

Comment: HTML code doesn't have angularjs \*connected\*, but if you select 'No wrap - in <body>' it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, only one change is required- add your `javacript code` in `<head>` tag by using `no wrap in <head>` in `LOAD TYPE` dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the `LOAD TYPE` in fiddle configured to `onLoad`

Change that to a `No Wrap` and will work fine

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vfbvsn7g/9/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be issue with loading of js

updated the inclusion dropdown to `no wrap in head` and its working

```
Fiddle :
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vfbvsn7g/6/